# Proving convergence of a generalized integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^a}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

So the problem i am having is proving that this integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^a}dx$$ 
converges for any $a \in (1,\infty)$

So the basic idea i have  is to try and divide the integral into two integrals but i dont know if it is the right way.

Comment: It's always best to make you title as specific as possible. It will greatly improve your chances to get an answer

Comment: "divide the integral into two integrals " - Please explain this in more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  the *Comparison theorem*: on the interval $ [1,+\infty)$
$$0\le\frac{\arctan x}{1+x^a}\le\frac{\pi}{2x^a}$$
The latter converge if and only if $a>1$.

Comment: While this development guarantees convergence for $a<1$, it doesn't imply that the integral of interest diverges otherwise.

Comment: I didn't say so. If and only if is for ‘the latter’.

Comment: Bernard, I realize that.  In fact the question doesn't ask for more.  So, +1.  I was only trying to expand on the question of convergence/divergence.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$, you have
$$
\frac {\arctan  (x)}{1+x^a}\leq\frac {\pi/2}{1+x^a}\leq\frac\pi {2x^a}\leq\frac2 {x^a}.
$$